# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I am trying to download one file from my local server using curl.i am using command

```
curl   -L -O --retry 999 --retry-max-time 0 -C - http://192.168.1.74/gio-v2-9515.dd -u ajay:aj123
```

For experiment purpose i disconnected my Internet connection for two minutes but  according to this will resume automatically .But in my case i am getting error "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer".At the same time if i reconnect the connection with in 3 sec or 5 secs its will resume automaticaaly.so whats the actual issue.Any help would be appreciated .My local sever is working in Windows and my local machine is Ubuntu

Comment: I am really interested about the answer to this because I do observe this error in our build logs and I want to make them more-reliable by enabling curl retries.

Comment: The curl option `--retry-all-errors` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `--retry-all-errors`

> Retry on any error. This option is used together with --retry.

Added in 7.71.0.

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

`--retry-connrefused` will not work with a `Connection reset by peer` error